# JSP: The method sendStatus(int, String) is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to send back an HTTP coded with some HTML.  I get "the method sendStatus(int, String) is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse" error.  I also tried with only the code.  If I use sendError() instead, then the HTML is not sent.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<%@ page isErrorPage = "true"%>
<%response.sendStatus(500, "TEST 500 ERROR WITH HTML PAGE");%>

<html>
<body>
<h1>
Test HTTP Error: 500 ERROR with HTML page
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting:

```
ERROR_500_subjectdoc_htmlheader_error_realhtmlerrorpage.jsp:3:12: The method sendStatus(int, String) is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse
<%response.sendStatus(500, "TEST 500 ERROR WITH HTML PAGE");%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean the deprecated [`setStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setStatus%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method instead? Or perhaps [`sendError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)? The error message is pretty clear - there's no such method as `sendStatus(int, String)`, and the documentation confirms this.

Do you *really* need to set a message with the status though? Any reason not to just use `setStatus(500)`?

Comment: I still get The method sendStatus(int) is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse

Comment: @user994165: You need to pay close attention - I didn't say *send*Status, I said *set*Status.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `setStatus(int, String)` or the `sendError(int, String)` methods on HttpServletResponse

[HttpSevletResponse javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendError%28int%29)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks but if I do that then I can't send any HTML even if I sendError after the HTML.  If I do a redirect in JSP then the page ends up with an HTTP 200.  Do you know how to get an HTTP header and have HTML on the page?

Comment: On java web projects you can customize the error pages by editing the web.xml file http://www.javabeat.net/examples/2009/02/24/error-pages-in-jsp-2-0/ you just need to send error and then handle the error on the appropriate error page.

Comment: Thanks but this is the page I want to handle the page on. I don't want to redirect.  I want an HTTP error to be sent back and to also display the HTML page.  SendError just sends back the error and won't process the HTML.  I tried endStatus(500) but still getting "The method sendStatus(int) is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse"

Comment: Oh I get it, well, make sure you set the status before the response buffer is flushed, then it should work (this means check everything at the top of the file).